# Android Retrofit2 optional @Path param

Tags: android, retrofit2

In my andorid app I am making a GET request using Retrofit2:

```
http://myapi.com/items/list
```

But I would also like to make another request e.g.

```
http://myapi.com/items/list/filter/active:true,min_price:100
```

So the **filter parameter is optional**. I am trying to do the following:

```
@GET("items/items/list{filter}")
Observable<ResponseItems> getItems(@Path("filter") String filter);
```

and calling it like:

```
service.getItems("")
```

and:

```
service.getItems("/filter/active:true,min_price:100")
```

But it does not work. So I ended up creating two separate service calls, one with filter param and other without. I think that there should be more elegant method though.

Comment: try pass null instead of empty string. It is working for query params. For path params your requirement is a bit wierd. I think that using separate api calls is ok. Just like typical java class with overloaded methods

Comment: @Beloo Yes, but if your API user more than one of those optional path params, then calling it becomes really difficult and code really ugly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So i've seen what you are trying to achieve.

How your api declaration should looks like:

```
@GET("items/list/{filter}")
Observable<ResponseItems> getItems(@Path(value = "filter", encoded = true) String filter);
```

and a call `service.getItems("")` would lead to `http://myapi.com/items/list/` be called
a call `service.getItems("filter/active:true,min_price:100")` would lead to 
`http://myapi.com/items/list/filter/active:true,min_price:100` be called.

An `encoded` property in `@Path` annotation is set because your optional path parameter contains `/` and retrofit encodes it without that property.

So as i wrote in comments better use two declarations:

```
@GET("items/list/")
Observable<ResponseItems> getItems();

@GET("items/list/filter/{filter}")
Observable<ResponseItems> getItems(@Path(value = "filter") String filter);
```

so you may call it like `service.getItems("active:true,min_price:100")`

Comment: Although it can works, implies to maintain two implementations not makes sense for me, maybe you can consider set @Url.

Answer (score 2):

In simple word make method over loading. Create two method with same name and different parameter. Check my below source code. (written in kotlin)

```
@GET("myportal/news/{id}")
fun getNewsList(@Path("id") id: String): Call<NewsEntity>

@GET("myportal/news/{id}/{dateTime}")
fun getNewsList(@Path("id") id: Long, @Path("dateTime") dateTime: String): Call<NewsEntity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use HashMap to send optional params in a request, this allows you to send single/multiple optional params in your request also if you send the HashMap empty it will not affect your request.
Your interface will contain code like snippet below

```
@POST("yourUrl")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<YourResponse> yourApiRequest(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                                          @Field("mandatoryParam") int mandatoryParam,
                                          @FieldMap Map<String, String> optionalParamMap);
```

And your API call will be something like the following

```
private HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("optionalParam1", value1);
hashMap.put("optionalParam2", value2);
ApiClient.getApiClient().getApiInterface().yourApiRequest(token,
            mandatoryParam, hashMap)
            .enqueue(new Callback<YourResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<YourResponse> call, Response<YourResponse> response) {
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<YourResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

In a case where you don't want to send any optional params you can pass an empty hashmap to your request.